How to listen to incoming calls using GetStream React SDK?
I understand that you need to pass in an call object to StreamCall component, but how can you obtain the call object when you are not the  side that creates the call?
I tried to use useCall hook but it is definately not what I'm looking for.
I tried to listen to the events on client, like this
client.on("call.created", (event)=>{
            event.call;
})

But how do I create the call object and pass to react components after that?
